# Ionic 2 - How To Edit Searchbar Values Programmatically

Tags: angular, search, ionic-framework, ionic2, searchbar

How can I modify an ionic searchbar programatically in Ionic 2? I searched this for a while and did not come across anything that solves it.

I want to access & modify the default methods of the searchbar object from the searchview.ts. (e.g. inside onClear(), call onCancel() & navigate to a different view).
This is the searchbar in my html file.

```
<ion-searchbar [showCancelButton]="true" (ionClear)="onClear()">
</ion-searchbar>
```

I want to do something like;

```
onClear(){
    var searchbar = this.searchbar // reference the search bar in the html file, but how do I get this?
    searchbar.onCancel();
    this.navigateToHome();
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: added code sample. Modified the example to calling onCancel() from onClear(), instead of vice versa.

Comment: are you looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955880/how-to-extend-ionic2-tab-component

Comment: what searchbar values are you talking about ?? please provide example code

Comment: Just create a custom component with the features you want. I wouldnt want to screw the stock features that are shipped with the framework

Comment: Why not just call a method on the onClear event that navigates to a different view?

Comment: @suraj creating a custom component seems a like a bit too much work for this, although that could definitely be a solution. Can I do it without creating a custom component?

Comment: @Ivaro18, I want to access and trigger the provided default ionCancel() method.

Comment: @LeRoy, I provided sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I did not know how to ask the question right, I should have asked how do you access a child component/view in the html from the controller;

```
<ion-searchbar #mySearchBar (ionCancel)="onCancel()"></ion-searchbar>
```

Then access it like this;

```
@ViewChild('mySearchBar') searchbar:Searchbar;
```

and use it like this;

```
this.searchbar.ionCancel()
```

The whole code;

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Searchbar } from 'ionic-angular';

export class DictionaryPage {
    @ViewChild('mySearchBar') searchbar:Searchbar;

    constructor(){
         this.searchbar.ionCancel()}
}
```

Comment: If you just wanted to set value to blank then No need to call cancel event for setting value. You can also set searchbar's value to null using this code       `this.mysearchbarname.setValue(null);`
write this code inside constructor or your initialization function or **ionViewWillEnter** lifecycle event.